# Why the training of a neural network using binary cross-entropy loss function gets stuck when we use real-valued training targets?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

Assume that we have a binary classification problem, in which the training targets are not in {0,1} but in [0,1]. We use the following code to train a simple classifier in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(X,y)
```

If we pass the real training targets (in [0,1]), the training hardly proceeds, getting stuck around its initial loss value; but if we quantize the targets in {0,1} it performs better, rapidly decreases the training loss.

Is this a normal phenomena? What is its reason?

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/h-amirkhani/logistic-regression-temp) is the reproducible experiment.
And this is the obtained plot:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @today I added the link to an example in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you want to solve a binary classification task, for which the target should be **binary**-valued, i.e. {0,1}.

However, if your target instead is some float value in [0,1], you are actually trying to perform **regression**.

This, amongst others, changes the requirements for your loss function.
See [Tensorflow Cross Entropy for Regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223256/tensorflow-cross-entropy-for-regression), where the usage of cross entropy loss for regression is discussed in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In essence, my problem is binary classification, but I have the amount of "belonging" to each class for the training data. Anyway, my question is still remained: (whether you call it regression or classification) why using real-valued targets in binary cross-entropy makes problem in the learning process?